# Which version of iOS is the May 12 security paper referring to?

Tags: ios, security

Apple has published a [paper](http://images.apple.com/ipad/business/docs/iOS_Security_May12.pdf) on security controls in iOS, which specific version is this referring to?

Answer (score 4):

The given information seems pretty generic to me. A statement of how Apple manages security with the iOS devices seems more plausible rather than how security is handled with a specific version of it.

**iOS 5** is referred a couple of times in the paper, though, while no earlier version are, but in a very vague way.

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess by saying iOS 5, simply because of the date.